# RBAC in webapp2 with ACL from tipfy

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2, rbac, tipfy

I'm trying to implement an RBAC in webapp2. I find out some code of the framework project called tipfy that do this with ACL (access control list).

This is the code of the ACL module:

https://github.com/moraes/tipfy/blob/master/tipfy/appengine/acl.py

But I don't see how to use this code inside a handler in webapp2.
The documentation there says:

> "This requires the handler to have the area and current_user
>   attributes."

What's an Area? and how do I use this inside a handler?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I find out that area can be anything you want and it's up to you what meaning it has.

Just define a property in your handler that return some string ... and that's the area.

Also ... I Finally end up coding a RBAC for google app engine as I find ACL from tipfy to broad and difficult to use. However I based this project mainly in the ACL for tipfy.

You can find my approach here:

https://github.com/janscas/gae-rbac